# Java8 lambda syntax

Tags: java, lambda

I am learning the lambda syntax of java 8 and came across this piece of code which i have trouble understanding:

```
@Bean
public SomeBean somemethod() {
    return (a, b) -> {
        if (a.somemethodofb()) {
           ...
            a.somemethodofa();
            ...
        }
        return b;
    };
}
```

My question is this being a simple bean and not overriding anything else, how does it interpret the type of parameters a and b and invoke their respective methods? I mean, looking at this:(a, b), how do i know what is a and b? May be i am missing something obvious?

Comment: what is the definition of SomeBean?

Comment: you can see it https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SomeBean` would have to be an interface with one method of two parameters for this to compile. The types of those two parameters would be the types of `a` and `b`.

For example, if `SomeBean` was:

```
public class SomeBean {
    B doSomething(A a, B b);
}
```

Then the types of `a` and `b` in the lambda would be `A` and `B` respectively.

Comment: SomeBean is indeed a funv=ctional interface with the method taking a and b. Thank you!